# how to fix blurry screenshot display in windows photos app?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-8-photos-app

this is the screenshot and what it looks like in photos https://www.dropbox.com/s/7l6om5y4sfiv0hp/Screenshot%202015-01-30%2023.16.09.png?dl=0 https://www.dropbox.com/s/66nis20tqa83nhm/Screenshot%202015-01-30%2023.16.20.png?dl=0

if i change the windows width to 1920/2 it's sharp https://www.dropbox.com/s/47pzmjhmog6gvjh/Screenshot%202015-01-30%2023.18.06.png?dl=0 https://www.dropbox.com/s/kxticbs0zbqd5n8/Screenshot%202015-01-30%2023.18.16.png?dl=0

all 1920 wide pictures are blurry

### no google solution

theres no answer at https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+8.1+photos+app+blurry

Answer (score 3):

They appear blurry because the image itself is 1920 pixels wide, and so is your screen resolution. But because you view it in an application that has an interface itself, the image is shrinked slightly so everything is visible and no scrollbars are shown.

If you open the full sized image in the photoviewer, and then go full-screen preview, it will show crisp as it should.

Comment: the photos app has no borders

Comment: Believe me, it is shrinking the image down which causes the blur. Either horizontally or vertically it can't fit the entire screen, thus sizing it down a little bit to show all. And showing it full-screen solves it.

Comment: My advice, try a different viewer. May be a bug in the photoviewer app.